# If ESENT complains that it cannot create its logfile, is it avoidable?

Tags: windows-10, event-log

In my installation of Windows 10 on a fairly new machine that shipped with it, I get a lot of errors in my eventvwr log, and some of them I feel are indicative of why my system hits 100% disk use for about 10 minutes at a time on boot.

Specifically I'm looking at this relatively simple looking recurring error:

> SettingSyncHost (6440) An attempt to open the file "C:\Windows\system32\edbtmp.log" for read / write access failed with system error 5 (0x00000005): "Access is denied. ".  The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).

These are followed by:

> SettingSyncHost (6440) Unable to create a new logfile because the database cannot write to the log drive. The drive may be read-only, out of disk space, misconfigured, or corrupted. Error -1032.

They're repeated about 12 times in pairs.

I note that it comes from Source `ESENT` which is a basic part of the system, the extensible storage engine in nt, right? And I figure that there's no reason this should occur if Microsoft had configured these components as part of Windows and setup the disk etc.

The file in question doesn't exist. Under Windows 8 I see some people recommend to delete the file and the error will go away as the file is recreated, but I can't do that when it can't be created. So I made the file and System and Administrators are allowed to write to it. I added the write permission to my own user.

The error doesn't seem to have gone away though. It occurs when the system wakes from sleep and when it boots.

Has anyone seen this in Windows 10 and resolved it?

Comment: If you create the file, and give it the proper permissions, what happens?

Comment: I continue to get these errors with the permissions I described (r+exec, r, w for system, administrators, my user, plus full control and modify for system and administrators). So it would seem I don't know which other permission to give and to whom.